# Efficient algorithm for maximum value and its index in Swift array

Tags: arrays, swift, max

I have written an algorithm is Swift for finding the maximum value and its index in a Swift array. This is inspired by the "max.m" function in Matlab & Octave.

Could the experts here suggest a way to improve this algorithm in terms of speed? I mean could it be made faster or you think this is a reasonable approach for large arrays (sometimes 15000 samples).

```
public func max (y: [Double]) -> (Int, Double) {

let inLen = y.count

var out = Double()
var outp = Int()

if (1 == inLen) { // if only one element
    out = y[0]
    outp = 0
} else if (0 == inLen) { // if no elements
    out = -1
    outp = -1
} else {
    out = y[0]
    outp = 0
    for ii in 1...inLen-1 {
        if (out<y[ii]){
            out = y[ii]
            outp = ii
        }
    }
}
return (outp, out)
}

// Call the function

let y: [Double] = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 100, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -8, -7, -7, 99]
let (ind, value) = max(y: y)
print(ind) // 7
print(value) // 100.0
```

Comment: Are you looking for a code review? Because there's **a lot** that can be improved in this code.

Comment: Hi Alexander -- yes I think so! Should I post it in code review?

Comment: it's fine here. I'm working my way through it, it'll take me a while, there's a lot to change.

Comment: Ok thanks Alexander!

Comment: I'm done my first go at it. Performance will probably be the same, but the quality is much improved! Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`vDSP_maxviD)()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1449682-vdsp_maxvid)
function from the Accelerate framework. The vDSP functions use
[`vDSP_Length`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/vdsp_length)
(aka `UInt`) for array counts and indices, so you have to convert the
index to an `Int` for Swift interoperability.

```
import Accelerate

let array: [Double] = ...

var elem = 0.0
var vdspIndex: vDSP_Length = 0
vDSP_maxviD(array, 1, &elem, &vdspIndex, vDSP_Length(array.count))
let idx = Int(vdspIndex)

print("max:", elem, "at index:", idx)
```

This turned out to be about a factor 5 faster than your explicit
loop for a 15,000 element array (on an iMac compiled in Release mode).

Comment: Thanks Alexander & Martin! Martin, with the vDSP_maxviD function, it seems I have to cast idx as Int(idx) if I want to use it to get element of another array or if I need to add an integer to it. I have read here that casting especially inside a loop is not good as it consumes time. How to overcome the casting of idx?

Comment: @Pat: You only have to convert the index to an Int once. That is negligible compared to the vDSP_maxviD call.

Comment: @Pat I provide a wrapper for this code at the bottom of my answer. It makes it so that externally, you only deal with nice Swift types/conventions

Answer (score 6):

## Code Review on the original code

Here are the changes I would make. All this is kind of rough (I haven't checked if all these compile), but will put you on the right track.

1. Make the code generic

   ```
   public func max (y: [Double]) -> (Int, Double) {
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   public func max<T: Comparable>(y: [T]) -> (Int, T) {
   ```
2. Remove the useless parameter keyword `y`, and rename `y` to something meaningful

   ```
   public func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> (Int, T) {
   ```
3. Add keywords to the result:

   ```
   public func max<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> (index: Int, value: T) {
   ```
4. Add it as an extension on `Array` or `RandomAccessCollection`, replacing the need for the parameter entirely:

   ```
   extension Array where Element: Comparable {
       public func max() -> (index: Int, value: Element) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
5. Inline the unnecessary variable `inLen`, or at least name it better, like just `count`
6. Rename `out` and `outp` to something better, such as `maxValue` and `maxIndex`
7. Don't use yoda comparisons in Swift. `=` isn't an exprission in Swift, so there's no risk of it accidentally causing assignment in your if statement rather than comparison. It would trigger a compiler error. Also, omit the

   ```
   if (1 == count) {
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if (count == 1) {
   ```
8. Omit uneeded parathesis in the if statements:

   ```
   if count == 1 {
   ```
9. Rearrange the count checks in a more logical order. Rather than 1, 0, 1+, order it as 0, 1, 1+.
10. Return early, rather than using if/elseif/else to skip chunks of code to get to a common return. Instead of:

    ```
    extension Array where Element: Comparable {
        public func max() -> (index: Int, value: Element) {
            var maxValue = Double()
            var maxIndex = Int()

            if count == 0 { // if no elements
                maxValue = -1
                maxIndex = -1
            } else if count == 1 { // if only one element
                maxValue = self[0]
                maxIndex = 0
            } else {
                maxValue = self[0]
                maxIndex = 0
                for i in 1...inLen-1 {
                    if (maxValue < self[i]){
                        maxValue = self[i]
                        maxIndex = i
                    }
                }
            }
            return (index: maxIndex, value: maxValue)
        }
    }
    ```

    try this:

    ```
    extension Array where Element: Comparable {
        public func max() -> (index: Int, value: Element)? {
            var maxValue = Double()
            var maxIndex = Int()

            if count == 0 { return (index: -1, value: -1) } 
            if count == 1 { return (index: 0, value: self[0]) }

            maxValue = self[0]
            maxIndex = 0
            for i in 1...count-1 {
                if (maxValue < self[i]) {
                    maxValue = self[i]
                    maxIndex = i
                }
            }
            return (index: maxIndex, value: maxValue)
        }
    }
    ```
11. Now you can remove the forward declarations of `maxValue` and `maxIndex`

    ```
    extension Array where Element: Comparable {
        public func max() -> (index: Int, value: Element) {
            if count == 0 { return (index: -1, value: -1) } 
            if count == 1 { return (index: 0, value: self[0]) }

            var maxValue = self[0]
            var maxIndex = 0
            for i in 1...count-1 {
                if (maxValue < self[i]) {
                    maxValue = self[i]
                    maxIndex = i
                }
            }
            return (index: maxIndex, value: maxValue)
        }
    }
    ```
12. Avoid rewriting things like `1 ... x-1` instead, use `..<`:
        for i in 1 ..< count {
13. In this case, it's even better to use self.indices, which achieves the same thing:

    ```
    for i in self.indicies {
    ```
14. If you need both the indices, and the values assosiated with those indices, use `enumerated()`:

    ```
    for (index, value) in self.enumerated() {
    ```
15. Never use sentinel values like `-1` and `""` in Swift. We have optionals for expressing the absense of a value. Use them:

    ```
    extension Array where Element: Comparable {
        public func max() -> (index: Int, value: Element)? {
            if count == 0 { return nil } 
            if count == 1 { return (index: 0, value: self[0]) }

            var maxValue = self[0]
            var maxIndex = 0
            for (index, value) in self.enumerated() {
                if (maxValue < value) {
                    maxValue = value
                    maxIndex = index
                }
            }
            return (index: maxIndex, value: maxValue)
        }
    }
    ```
16. I would also use tuple assignment to make a bit shorter:

    ```
    extension Array where Element: Comparable {
        public func max() -> (index: Int, value: Element)? {
            if count == 0 { return nil } 
            if count == 1 { return (index: 0, value: self[0]) }

            var (maxIndex, maxValue) = (0, self[0])
            for (index, value) in self.enumerated() {
                if (maxValue < value) {
                    (maxIndex, maxValue) = (index, value)
                }
            }
            return (index: maxIndex, value: maxValue)
        }
    }
    ```
17. Now that we're using tuple assignment, we can see that we can just combine maxValue and maxIndex into a tuple, which we return directly:

    ```
    extension Array where Element: Comparable {
        public func max() -> (index: Int, value: Element)? {
            if count == 0 { return nil } 
            if count == 1 { return (index: 0, value: self[0]) }

            var maxElement = (index: 0, value: self[0])
            for (index, value) in self.enumerated() {
                if (maxElement.value < value) { maxElement = (index, value) }
            }
            return maxElement
        }
    }
    ```

Here's how to call the new method:

```
let array: [Double] = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 100, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -8, -7, -7, 99]

if let (maxIndex, maxValue) = array.max() {
    print("The max element is \(maxValue) at index \(maxIndex)")
}
else {
    print("The array is empty, and has no max element or index.")
}
```

## The idomatic Swift approach

```
let array: [Double] = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 100, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -8, -7, -7, 99]

if let (maxIndex, maxValue) = array.enumerated.max{ $0.element < $1.element } {
    print("The max element is \(maxValue) at index \(maxIndex)")
}
else {
    print("The array is empty, and has no max element or index.")
}
```

## MartinR's approach, improved

Here's a wrapper around MartinR's approach, to make it easier to integrate with other Swift code:

```
func max(of array: [Double]) -> (index: Int, value: Double)? {
    var maxValue = Double()
    var maxIndex = vDSP_Length()
    vDSP_maxviD(array, 1, &maxValue, &maxIndex, vDSP_Length(array.count))

    if maxValue == -Double.infinity { return nil }

    return (index: Int(maxIndex), value: maxValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Martin R answer there is a cleaner way since iOS 13.0 / macOS 10.15

```
import Accelerate

let array: [Double] = [1,2,3.8,4,3,3,5,4,3,4]

let (idx, max) = vDSP.indexOfMaximumMagnitude(array)
print("max:", max, "at index:", idx)
```