# how to get number of maximum element in array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, max, element

How to solve it? I should get 2 in this case.

```
var r = [1, 3, 5]
r.max() // gives 5
```

ps: new quality standarts when posting - is something crazy...

Comment: I dont understand. Is it two because of the 1 and 5?

Comment: @AaronZheng He's looking to get the index

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Efficient algorithm for maximum value and its index in Swift array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128950/efficient-algorithm-for-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-swift-array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would go about doing it:

```
let array = [1, 3, 5]

if let (maxIndex, maxValue) = array.enumerated().max(by: { $0.element < $1.element }) {
    print("The max element is \(maxValue) at index \(maxIndex)")
}
else {
    print("The array is empty, and has no max element or index.")
}
```