# Fastest way to compare n arrays of integers in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, compare

I'm trying to find a really fast way of comparing n arrays of integers in Swift. Actually I'm looking to compare a struct, but the same principle applies. There are various ways I could do this using loops etc, but as the arrays will be large, and I need to do this at a high refresh rate I was wondering if anyone had any better ideas?

```
let array1 = [0,255,128]
let array2 = [255,128,0]
let array3 = [128,0,0]

// result [255,255,128]
```

A more accurate example would be to find the highest 'priority' and then find the highest 'level' where priorities match

```
let array1 = [(level: 0, priority: 200),(level: 255, priority: 100), (level: 128, priority: 200)]
let array2 = [(level: 255, priority: 100),(level: 128, priority: 100), (level: 0, priority: 0)]
let array3 = [(level: 128, priority: 200),(level: 0, priority: 200), (level: 0, priority: 0)]

// result [128,0,128]
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Let n be the number of elements in each of the arrays, you must loop at least n times. Or else you can't compare every element.

Comment: See this answer for an alternative max function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42129847/1305067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to compare every element of your arrays then you will have to loop through the entire set of arrays at least once.  I think the best you can do is try to make it really easy on yourself by creating a Struct with a helper function for performing the comparison just to reduce the amount of code you need.  My best shot looks like this:

```
struct LevelPriority {
    let level: Int
    let priority: Int

    func isHigher(thanOther other: LevelPriority) -> Bool {
        if self.priority == other.priority {
            return self.level >= other.level
        }
        return self.priority > other.priority
    }
}

let array1 = [LevelPriority(level: 0, priority: 200),LevelPriority(level: 255, priority: 100), LevelPriority(level: 128, priority: 200)]
let array2 = [LevelPriority(level: 255, priority: 100),LevelPriority(level: 128, priority: 100), LevelPriority(level: 0, priority: 0)]
let array3 = [LevelPriority(level: 128, priority: 200),LevelPriority(level: 0, priority: 200), LevelPriority(level: 0, priority: 0)]

var result = Array<LevelPriority>.init(repeating: LevelPriority(level: 0, priority: 0), count: 3)

[array1, array2, array3].forEach({
    result[0] = $0[0].isHigher(thanOther: result[0]) ? $0[0] : result[0]
    result[1] = $0[1].isHigher(thanOther: result[1]) ? $0[1] : result[1]
    result[2] = $0[2].isHigher(thanOther: result[2]) ? $0[2] : result[2]
})

print(result) 
//prints [LevelPriority(level: 128, priority: 200), LevelPriority(level: 0, priority: 200), LevelPriority(level: 128, priority: 200)]

let levelOnly = result.map({ $0.level })
print(levelOnly)
//prints [128, 0, 128]
```

Of course this solution assumes that all arrays are of the same length, and that you know the length.  If that is not the case then you can use some other method to determine when to stop looping safely.

Comment: This seems like a great suggestion. Thanks so much!

Comment: Why don't you simply make LevelPriority conform to comparable protocol?

Comment: @LeoDabus, it actually already is. What I was trying to find was the fastest way of comparing the arrays. I have potentially 5 arrays of 512 x LevelPriority objects and I need to evaluate 40/s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
typealias levelPriorityTuple = (level: Int, priority: Int)

func > (tuple1:levelPriorityTuple,tuple2:levelPriorityTuple) -> Bool {
    return tuple1.priority == tuple2.priority ? tuple1.level > tuple2.level : tuple1.priority > tuple2.priority
}

let array1 : [levelPriorityTuple] = [(level: 0, priority: 200),(level: 255, priority: 100), (level: 128, priority: 200)]
let array2 : [levelPriorityTuple] = [(level: 255, priority: 100),(level: 128, priority: 100), (level: 0, priority: 0)]
let array3 : [levelPriorityTuple] = [(level: 128, priority: 200),(level: 0, priority: 200), (level: 0, priority: 0)]

var result = [Int]()
var arrays = [array1, array2, array3]

if !arrays.isEmpty {
    var tempArray = arrays[0]
    arrays.forEach{arr in result = Array(zip(tempArray, arr)).map{$0.0 > $0.1 ? $0.0 : $0.1}.map{$0.level}}
}
print(result)
//[128, 0, 128]
```

You only need to validate that each of the arrays is the same size, you can add as many arrays as you want

Comment: This is another good solution. I'm going to take a look at both of these and see if one is faster than the other.